# How to move the color bar of a heatmap in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, heatmap, colorbar

I'm plotting some heatmaps in gnuplot. It has the graph and a colorbar in the right side of the graph. But I wish to change it's position in the plot. Does anybody know the command to change the position of the colorbar in the plot ??

Thanks,

Thiago

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the command `set colorbox`:

```
set colorbox vertical user origin .02, .1 size .04,.8
```

If you want it anywhere but the default position you have to set the coordinates manually.  For more info you can type

```
help set
```

in gnuplot and all the options starting with `cb` and `colorbox` refer to fine points of the colorbox.

Comment: Thank you a lot. That's exacly what I need.